# How can I programmatically join 2 contacts in android?

Tags: android, api, join, merge, contacts

I need to know if is it possible to join two or more contacts (in a programmatic way, using the Contacts android API or something).

For example, I have a contact "Axel Rose" with an email account and a phone number, 
and I've noticed that some apps like whatsapp, Facebook and Skype are creating new contact entries for Axel Rose, instead of merging the existing one.

I can join contacts using the "Join feature" from the phone, but is there a programmatic way?

Thanks in advance.
Cristian.

Comment: Yes this is doable, but seems too large of a coding answer to do for you.  But you would need to find the contacts, grab all the information, delete the old ones and create a new one that is combined.  I would start here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Comment: @MichaelWildermuth put that in as the answer please. Your telling him how to do it and that is exactly what he's asking for, code answers isn't always the best answer.

Comment: @crist Did you get any applicable solution for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AggregationExceptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html). See [How to manual aggregate contacts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/16d_y1y4KNI) ?

A good place to understand how contacts and aggregation works is [Contacts Provider Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)

Short summary:

The contacts that you see on your phonebook are the ones on the ContactsContract.Contacts table. The photo, phone, etc shown on the phonebook comes from different RawContacts entries. A contact can have one o several RawContacts.

A Contact happens to have several RawContact when the RawContacts share some data on common (name, phone number, email, etc). The union of this RawContacts into a single Contact is made by automatic aggregation rules (see [Contact Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#ContactBasics) docs).

You can't insert contacts on the ContactsContract.Contacts table. 
From the documentation:

> Note: If you try to add a contact to the Contacts Provider with an insert(), you'll get an UnsupportedOperationException exception. If you try to update a column that's listed as "read-only," the update is ignored.

Comment: I can't find the part on the docs you've shown, that talks about the merge/linking of contacts. Is there maybe a tutorial for this? I've noticed, for example that the newest contacts app of Google allows to link/merge multiple contacts. Is it open sourced? How does it work? Can you please show a sample code of merging/linking contacts?